# Free vs. encapsulation

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, malloc, free

In programming there is a general rule introduced by Kernighan & Ritchie saying that you have call a "free" for all space allocated by a "malloc".

So the following code is correct:

```
- (UIImage*) convertImage:(UIImage*)sourceImage {
   unsigned char *rawData = malloc(requiredSpace);
   ...
   ...
   free(rawData);
   return imageRef;
}
```

However you also have encapsulation within a function. So after the return from the function, the memory will be automatically freed. So theoretically the free is not absolutely required in the above example. Is this correct?

Comment: What kind of sorcery is this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely no.

The `free` is necessary since the memory will be freed only for statically allocated variables. If you use `malloc` (as well as `calloc` or `realloc`) you are dynamically allocating memory that will not be freed except if you explicitly call `free`.

For example:

```
-(void)method {

    char a[10];
    char *b = (char*) malloc(10*sizeof(char));

}
```

`a` will be destroyed at the end of the scope (at least, will be marked as free memory, so that you cannot rely anymore on its content), while `b` remains in memory until the end of the program. If you lose the pointer to that memory address (maybe assigning another value to `b` or simply ending the function without returning `b`), you will not be able to free the memory anymore, and this will bring to a memory leak.